# Yii style pagination with CActiveDataProvider or CListView

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I want to change the class of the Yii pagination. It looks terrible.
But i don't know how to change the class. I tried many different things already, here's what i have now:

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Producten',array(
         'criteria'=>array(
         'condition'=>'categorie=:cat AND subcategorie=:subcat',
         'params'=>array(':cat'=>$cat,':subcat'=>$subcat),
     ),
     'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
        'naam', 'prijs'
     ),
     ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>1,
     ),
));
```

VIEW CODE:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'pag'), //<---------- THIS DOES NOT WORK
));
```

The Pagination works, but the styling is aweful.
The current class is: `yiiPager`

Please help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize your pagination style like below:

```
'pager' => array(
            'firstPageLabel' => '<<',
            'lastPageLabel' => '>>',
            'prevPageLabel' => '>',
            'nextPageLabel' => '<',
            'nextPageCssClass' => 'ClassName',
            'previousPageCssClass' => 'ClassName',
            'selectedPageCssClass' => 'ClassName',
            'internalPageCssClass' => 'ClassName',
        ),
'pagerCssClass' => 'ClassName'
```

Comment: You rock buddy! Only thing i need to change now is UL class `Yiipager`.

Comment: Great, Thanks. You can add it manually (override it) in a css file and put that in `pager` -> 'cssFile' =>'file.css'

Comment: Made some adjustments in the CLinkPager class. Now it works as i want it, but i don't know if that's the correct way.

Comment: That's it buddy. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager#firstPageLabel-detail . They are the canonical attributes of this widget

Comment: buddy, Do you know if there is a way to auto sort my products?

Comment: Doesn't `sort` satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Yes but its not in a dropdown list.. its an UL :(